# Handling Condtion in ThreadPoolExecutor to execute

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have the following Scenario.
There is a restroom in a Building.
It will have 2 types[As of now] of toilet. `MALE` and `FEMALE` which is n in number.

If a group of People enters into a restroom.I want them to occupy maximum no of rooms as possible.

Assume there are 20 people entering into restroom at a time with the following combination

```
People  20
Male 10 Female 10

RestRoom Avaialbiltiy
MALE 2
FEMALE 1
```

And some people will take more time, so the next person have to wait in the queue.And `male` cannot enter into `female` toilet and vice-versa.

For the above scenario I have extended the `ThreadpoolExecutor` and add the `Person` one by one and check assign them as soon as toilet with match is avaialable.

So here is the MCVE for the example.I wanted to check if this is the correct way to handle condition in a ThreadPool

**RestRoom.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum RestRoom {

    MALE,
    FEMALE;//will extend for ex [Differently Abled]

    public int maxInstance = 0;

    public RestRoom withMaxInstance(int maxInstance) {
        this.maxInstance = maxInstance;
        return this;
    }

    public static int getTotalNoOfRestRooms() {
        int count = 0;
        for (RestRoom room : RestRoom.values()) {
            count += room.maxInstance;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static Map<RestRoom, Integer> getAvailabiltyAsMap() {
        Map<RestRoom, Integer> avaialbilty = new HashMap<>();
        for (RestRoom room : RestRoom.values()) {
            avaialbilty.put(room, room.maxInstance);
        }
        return avaialbilty;
    }
}
```

**Person.java (Runnable)**

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Person implements Runnable {

    private final String name;

    private final RestRoom gender;

    private int second;

    public Person(String name, RestRoom gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Person withTime(int second) {
        this.second = second;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Running " + name + " with " + gender);
            Thread.sleep(second * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Person.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public RestRoom getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" + "name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender + '}';
    }

}
```

**CustomThreadPool.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CustomThreadPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    Map<RestRoom, Integer> avaialbilty = new HashMap<>();
    LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable> remaining = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();

    public CustomThreadPool(int corePoolSize, long keepAliveTime) {
        super(corePoolSize, corePoolSize, keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>());
        avaialbilty = RestRoom.getAvailabiltyAsMap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable runnable, Throwable throwable) {
        avaialbilty.put(getRestRoomFor(runnable), avaialbilty.get(getRestRoomFor(runnable)) + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining.size(); i++) {
            execute(remaining.remove());
        }
        if (remaining.isEmpty()) {
            shutdown();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        if (avaialbilty.get(getRestRoomFor(runnable)) > 0) {
            avaialbilty.put(getRestRoomFor(runnable), avaialbilty.get(getRestRoomFor(runnable)) - 1);
            super.execute(runnable);
        } else {
            remaining.add(runnable);
        }
    }

    private RestRoom getRestRoomFor(Runnable runnable) {
        return asPerson(runnable).getGender();
    }

    private Person asPerson(Runnable runnable) {
        return (Person) runnable;
    }

}
```

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestRoom.MALE.withMaxInstance(3);
        RestRoom.FEMALE.withMaxInstance(2);
        CustomThreadPool threadPool = new CustomThreadPool(RestRoom.getTotalNoOfRestRooms(), 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            threadPool.execute(new Person("M" + i, RestRoom.MALE).withTime(2));
            threadPool.execute(new Person("F" + i, RestRoom.FEMALE).withTime(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the review site, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this is the main question you have: "I wanted to check if this is the correct way to handle condition in a ThreadPool" But that question is still a little vague. There are many, many things I would change about this program if I were reviewing it, but it's not clear what you think might be a problem here specifically.